# Trouble with equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble simplifying this equation, and can't get the required result.

I need to show that:

$\large\frac{b^a}{(b+\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2)^{a+1/2}}=b^2 (1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2b})^{-(a+1/2)}$

Please help simplify!

Comment: Does $$\frac{b^a}{(b+\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2)^{a+\frac{1}{2}}}=b^ab^{-(a+\frac{1}{2})}(1+\frac{1}{2b}(x-\mu)^2)^{-(a+\frac{1}{2})}=b^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1+\frac{1}{2b}(x-\mu)^2)^{-(a+\frac{1}{2})}$$ help?

Comment: Obviously,a typo in the textbook !

Answer (score 1):

The denominator on the left is equal to $b^{a+1/2}\left(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2b}\right)^{a+1/2}$. The $b^a$ in front cancels the $b^a$ in the numerator. So we get
$$\frac{1}{b^{1/2}}\left(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2b}\right)^{-(a+1/2)}.$$
This is not equal to your target expression. The closest we get is $b^{-1/2}\left(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2b}\right)^{-(a+1/2)}$.